# Error initializing SQL Lite with CN1 Data Access

Tags: codenameone

I'm used to Codename One, but not to the database part, it's the first time I'm using it and I've run into some problems with the CN1 Data Access lib.

I'm using it's versionning capability, and I'm stuck. I'm trying to create a very simple table to achieve some image caching and I always got this exception :

```
java.io.IOException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ")": syntax error)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.SEDatabase.execute(SEDatabase.java:107)
    at ca.weblite.codename1.db.DAOProvider.getDatabaseSchema(DAOProvider.java:192)
    at ca.weblite.codename1.db.DAOProvider.loadSchema(DAOProvider.java:248)
    at ca.weblite.codename1.db.DAO.<init>(DAO.java:109)
    at our.app.managers.dao.TarotImgDAO.<init>(TarotImgDAO.java:14)
    at our.app.managers.DatabaseHelper.initialize(DatabaseHelper.java:78)
    at our.app.managers.DatabaseHelper.getInstance(DatabaseHelper.java:43)
    at our.app.App.init(App.java:95)
```

Here is the sql file :

```
--Version:1
CREATE TABLE tarot_img (
  id        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  img_path  VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  img       BLOB
);
--
```

I've tried it on the SQL lite db with DB Browser for SQL lite, and it's working.
Here is the calling code :

```
Database db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate(DB_FILE);
DBinstance = db;
DAOProvider provider = new DAOProvider(db, "/liquibase.sql", DB_VERSION);
provider.set("tarot_img", new TarotImgDAO(provider)); <--- IOExc here
```

And the TarotImgDAO constructor is :

```
public TarotImgDAO(DAOProvider provider) throws IOException {
    super("tarot_img", provider);
}
```

I really don't get why this super basic SQL fail, maybe something with the parsing ?

I've also had to replace the original lib with the one rebuild by kaya18 on [github](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-data-access-lib/issues/5#issuecomment-220916845) to overcome the NumberFormatException caused by a bad trim in the lib.

Any help would be welcome :)

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the `getDatabaseSchema` method of the DAO provider API which isn't an official part of Codename One. Since the lines don't map correctly I guess this might be an issue in the fork you used for the provider but I'll defer this to Steve

Comment: I have replied in the issue you posted at https://github.com/shannah/cn1-data-access-lib/issues/12.  Please follow progress there.

Comment: Everything works fine with the updated lib, thanks !